# Convert decimal number in binary don't work with long long type

Tags: c

This function not working for 4095.

```
long long convert(int decimalnum)
{
long long binarynum = 0;
int rem, temp = 1;

while (decimalnum!=0)
{
    rem = decimalnum%2;
    decimalnum = decimalnum / 2;
    binarynum = binarynum + rem*temp;
    temp = temp * 10;
}
return binarynum;
}

printf("%lld", convert(4095));
```

result is:-558038585

Is there a way to make the function work for this number?

Comment: what do you mean 'decimal number in binary'? Please show the output you expect

Comment: 7 in 111,16 in 10000

Comment: aha - ok I see now

Comment: `temp` is an `int`. It should be a `long long`.

Comment: For the record, this approach cannot possibly work for all values because you're expanding the number to its "binary" representation but storing it as if it's a base 10 number. It is not. Doing this introduces "gaps" in the numeric representation such that even a moderately large value will exceed the maximum storage bits for this representation. When converting a value to a binary _representation_, you should do that as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that temp will exceeds the range of possible values ​​for an integer number.
You should fix your code as follows:

```
long long convert(int decimalnum)
{
    long long binaryNum = 0;
    long long temp = 1;
    int rem = 1;
    .
    .
    .
}
```